# GDAL RasterIO performance in C++ vs ReadAsArray in python/numpy

Tags: python, gdal, c++, numpy

I'm currently writing optimisations for a raster viewer program which uses gdal as it's base. It's currently written purely in python, and has some major speed issues which cause problems when we are reading many files at a time.
After making some optimisations in the python, and getting quite a minimal speed increase, I proceeded to profile the program quite heavily and found that our getImage method was our slowest call. I had already performed some optimisations on this function so decided to write a C-Extension so that we could get some speed increases through a lower level language.

This has worked for the most part, however there is still one issue, we have found a speed increase of ~2s for some of our larger files in the bulk of the code. But this is negated by the GDALRasterIO call, which is actually about 3s slower than the python ReadAsArray.

This doesn't make any sense to me as ReadAsArray is a wrapper around a C++ call to GDALRasterIO, and thus should be slower than having a call straight to GDALRasterIO.

I was hoping someone here might know of a way to read the rasters more efficiently. I have tried to implement a method using ReadBlock rather than RasterIO, but due to the replication that RasterIO does it didn't work at all. (I'm currently trying to figure out a way to do that replication without losing too much speed).

The RasterIO call i'm using is

```
band->RasterIO(GF_Read, this->ovleft, this->ovtop, this->ovxsize,
               this->ovysize, dataTmp, this->ovxsize, this->ovysize,
               band->GetRasterDataType(), 0, 0);
```

The old python call was:

```
dataTmp = band.ReadAsArray(ovleft, ovtop, 
    ovxsize, ovysize,
    dspRastXSize, dspRastYSize)
```

Comment: look at  [rasterio](https://github.com/sgillies/rasterio) optimised for Numpy

Comment: Yeah, I know a few check here sometimes aswell though, so was hoping i'd be able to get a quick resolution.
@gene I've thought about using rasterio, but they want it to not have too many dependencies, So I'm doing it where if the cpp isn't availiable then it will carry on using the old version, otherwise it will use the hopefully faster version

Comment: The only dependencies of rasterio are GDAL(C++ library) and Numpy (ReadAsArray) and you say that the program uses gdal as it's base

Comment: rasterio's python dependencies(from the README file) are affine, cligj (and click), enum34, numpy, + gdal. All of which bar numpy and gdal are not installed on work computers, and would require users to install them aswell.

Comment: then post you question to the [GDAL-dev](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GDAL-Dev-f3742093.html) list

Comment: `ReadBlock` is the fastest way to read and you should also check the structure of your files (compressed, interleaved, tiled, what tiles, etc...). `ReadAsArray` should be very close to the maximum too - so it is not about Python vs C++ as both do the actual reading in C++